# Javascript promise - resolve (or) reject happening implicitly

Tags: javascript, promise

From chrome console, i am using native JS promises and it is getting resolved automatically,

```
var p = new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject){
    resolve(200)
})
```

returns

```
undefined

p.then(function(response){
  console.log(response)
})
```

returns

```
200
```

I think, Promise.then is meant for registering resolve (or) reject callbacks. But, why is it triggering resolve callback function itself in this case.

Comment: Don't be confused by the console reporting `undefined`. Examine the value of `p` explicitly and you will see that it is a resolved promise already (at the moment it is created).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it logging undefined?

Because a `var` statement has not useful return value. For example if you type `var x = 5` your console will log `undefined`.

> Why is it resolving?

Because you called `resolve` which is how you resolve a promise in the promise constructor.

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve(200)
});
```

Is basically the same as `var p = Promise.resolve(200)`. This isn't only explicitly resolving it - it's the only way to resolve it. If you want to not resolve it remove that `resolve(200)` line.

> But, why is it triggering resolve callback function itself in this case.

It is not, if you `console.log(p)` and remove the `then` part it will log a resolved promise.

Answer (score 1):

> Here, How & when does the resolve promise trigger happen?

The `then` callback is executed in some future next turn of the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop), if it is attached before the promise resolves. If it is attached after it has resolved, it will execute in the next turn, as if it was wrapped in a `setTimeout(function () {}, 0)` call.

> atleast in my 2 lines of code, i am not resolving it explicitly?

When you call `resolve`, yes, you are resolving the promise.

Comment: It registers callbacks that will be called when the promise is resolved, or ASAP if it is already resolved. The callback is "guaranteed to run." If you have used jQuery, it's like `$(document).ready`; it runs later, or it runs now.